# node js send html to network rather than only localhost server

Tags: node.js, http, express, server

I'm using node js trying to send my web-page to my network, I successfully call `localhost:port` in my computer using `express` as server, the webpage loads fine trigger my webcam which I used to streaming in the webpage, and then im working to make a simple app in my phone to directly access my server, so my questions:

1.How do I able to access my server from different devices in the same wireless-network? by calling ip + port ?192.168.1.104:9001 ? cause i've tried and it didnt work.

2.I've found https with `.pem` something like that, is that the answer ? is there also any other way ?

3.maybe any advice before i work to make my web-app to devices? using koa? i don't even really know what is that, but i'm happily take any advices.

EDIT: i've read [How could others, on a local network, access my NodeJS app while it's running on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on)

4. let's say I simply using random router, so i can't configure my router-port, my server in my pc and my phone join in the same network, trying to access the server in my phone

Comment: You need to host the express application on a server with a public routable ip address. `192.168.1.104` is a local ip for internal networking only. You would need to setup port forwarding (or a DMZ) in your router from your internet providers WAN ip address in order to use your home computer. I recommend you search for NODE.jS web hosts and use their platform since you are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @magreenberg I think OP want to access the server from intranet, not from internet: "access my server from different devices in the same wireless-network"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.How do I able to access my server from different devices in the same wireless-network?***

All you need to do is find your server's IP address in this *same wireless-network*, and find the Node.js application's port. Then access the following URL in other devices:

[http://{server_IP}:{port}](http://server:port)

However, there are some points need to check:

- Need to check firewall and confirm the port is not blocked, server IP is not blocked by test device, and test device IP is not blocked by server.
- Need to check whether there is any Proxy setting in server and test device. If there is any, disable the proxy.
- A computer may have many IP addresses at the same time, you need to find the correct one in the *same wireless-network*. For example, If you install a virtual machine software such as VMware and run a virtual system inside, your real computer will get IP address as `192.168.*.*` -- this IP address looks like an intranet IP in wireless-network, but it is not, and can never be accessed by test device.

***2.I've found https with .pem something like that, is that the answer?***

No, HTTPS has nothing to do with this problem. HTTPS just add security (based on HTTP layer), it does not impact any HTTP connectivity. Actually, to minify the problem, it is better to only use HTTP in your scenario.

There is only one very special case that may bring your problem by HTTPS -- the test machine is configured and will block any non-HTTPS connection for security.

***3.maybe any advice before i work to make my web-app to devices? using koa?***

My suggestion is: As there is an HTTP connectivity issue, the first step is trying to find the root cause of that issue. Thus, it is better to make a simplest HTTP server using native Node.js, no Koa, no Express. In this way, the complexity of server will be reduced, which makes root cause investigation easier.

After the HTTP connectivity issue is fixed, you can pick up Koa or Express or any other mature Node.js web framework to help the web-app work.

***4.let's say I simply using random router, so i can't...***

Do you mean your server get dynamic IP address by DHCP? As long as the IP is not blocked by test device, it does not matter.