# Using express Web-app on local area Network

Tags: node.js, express

I've used [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to create a simple node application.
And I've serve the application on port 3000 so that i can test it on my localhost.

However, i wanted to use my application on my local area network. (without deploying it on internet)
How can i do that?
I could not find that in express documentation.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', ...app goes here... );

app.listen(3000);
```

Like serving it on `192.168.16.104:8080` where users connected to my network can access my application.

Comment: Your application will be running on http://[your ip address here]:[port] if you try accessing it from other devices.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on

Comment: Thankyou @ITDerrickH , this solved my issue.