# How to host a node server

Tags: node.js, server

I can find a lot online about how to write a node server but I haven't been able to find anything on how to deploy it on a local network.

Could anyone tell me how to make my node server accessible within my LAN?

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on

Comment: Thanks both of you. I think I have been using the wrong search criteria as all I got was about publishing it to a hosting company.