# Open a node.js server on LAN using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Okay so I've just started studying node.js, and it's gotten to the point in which I want to acces the website from my phone, but none of the solutions online are working for me.

I'm starting the web server like this:

```
const express = require('express');

// Express app
const app = express();

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Listen for requests
app.listen(3000);

//Just some routing example
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('index', { title: 'Home', blogs})
});
```

I have tried changing "app.listen(3000);" for "app.listen(3000, 'ANY IP THAT APPEARED IN CMD IPCONFIG');"

As you may have guessed, it didn't work either.

I'm pretty lost in all of this, and I need your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try ngrok, it lets you expose local port through a proxy to their servers.

Answer (score 0):

To have Express open to your LAN you need to make sure your ports are open on your router.
From what I understand you are able to start the server and connect on your computer but you want to see it on your phone. That is less of an Express issue and more of "making sure your ports and IP are correct on your router". Typically routers block ports for protection reasons.

There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on) which might also help you with how the port forwarding etc. works for Express and how to solve it.

Comment: I have already seen that post, and none of the solutions worked for me. Anyways, thank you