# How to connect to node.js server from any ip

Tags: node.js, server, ip, backend

I want to create a private backend for an application I want to make, but I am having trouble connecting to my node server, I have the basic stuff right now,

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server running on port 300.')
```

But this only works for https://localhost:3000/, how do I make it so that if I have a separate computer on a separate connection, I can connect to this server?

I am not interested in just opening it to everyone but just to specific client IP's...

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings for port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

If the client IP's are on the same network as you, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on)

If you want people from anywhere to access your application, I suggest hosting it on something like Heroku (very easy to deploy, pretty good free tier). You can then create a whitelist of IPs in your express application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for any port forwarding using ngrok or configuration in your router

For downloading ngrok https://ngrok.com/ go to this link

For configuration your router it will take some searching in google based on what type of router your using

You must mention that your localhost or Nat Ip and your public IP to resolve here is NOIP refrence https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/

Comment: Ok thank you this looks like the thing im looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As you specified that you want the backend to be private, such that it can only be accessed by your specified node. You will have to host this node server on a cloud service or you can host it on your local machine by opening a port for the node server. Suppose you host the node server on port `1234` on your local machine ip address.

You can start the node server on localhost and your desired port, but you need to allow requests to the particular port.

Now you need to check for the origin of the request that your node server receives and validate that, so that only your private node(computer) can access the node server. You can do that by validating the hostname using express, you can get the hostname of the request in express.js using `req.hostname` or `req.headers.host`.

You would need to use express.js for this functionality and the code would be as follows

```js
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let allowedHost = 134.32.234.3 // the hostname which is allowed to access the backend
let port = 1234; // desired port
let host = 0.0.0.0 // desired host; 0.0.0.0 to host on your ip

app.get((req, res) => {
   res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   if(req.hostname == allowedHost){
       res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
    }
    else{
       res.send('Connection not allowed');
    }
});
app.listen(host, port, ()=>{
   console.log(`The server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh this is how its done this does make sense, I have a couple follow up questions though 1. For the client to connect, do I just do the server-host external ip address followed by its port number as a url? 2. What do you mean by allow request to the particular port, is this a thing that is done in the node code or by some other means?

Comment: @AskedSuperior 1. Yes, you just send request from the client to the server, the server url would be the server's IP Address and the specified port like this `http://IPAddress:Port`.

2. By "Allow request to the particular port" I mean that you should open the port for external requests as in most cases the port is not open for external requests, this is not done in the node.js code, this is a thing to be done on the firewall, if you are using a linux machine for hosting the server you would open the port for external requests by typing `ufw allow Port`

Comment: Follow up comment: 
This [digitalocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04) explains how to open a port