# Creating http web server doesn't work [Node js Express Mysql]

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, http

I've written Node.js app, using connect,It works fine as long as I am on localhost, but I can't get other computers on the same intranet to see it. I am using port 3306, but changing to port 8080 or 80 didn't help.

Here is the code I am using to set up the connection:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.1.117",
    user: "admin",
    password: "admin1",
    database : "db_test",
    port: 3306,
    connectionLimit : 1000
  });
const hostname = "192.168.1.117";
const port = 8080;

// Create HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  // Set the response HTTP header with HTTP status and Content type
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  // Send the response body "Hello World"
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});


 db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connecté à la base de données MySQL!");
  db.query("SELECT *  FROM data", function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    });
});

// Prints a log once the server starts listening
server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function() {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
})
```

I tried to test it with the postman but I didn't get no reponse. Can someone guide me to solve this issue please.

Comment: Have you tried the ideas and steps outlined in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on

Comment: Yeah I tried to allow nodejs in firewall & ip address of an other machine but not working