# Load a file from localSystem with javascript without a server

Tags: javascript, fetch

I make an app with javascript, I need to work with no any server in the local network. Only chrome browser run from /Services/ServiceFinder/index.html.

When load index.html need to read a XLSX file from the same directory **as a file**(i use the SheetJS library to read XLSX as a db and convert it to a javascript object).

I use fetch after window load event but i take an error message "The file is not loaded successfully."

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

//Get the file input
var file = "./ServicesData.XLSX";

//Load file
fetch(file, {mode: "no-cors"}).then(response => {

    if(response.ok) {
        console.log("%cThe file is loaded successfully.", styleConsoleLog);
    }else{
        console.error("The file is not loaded successfully.");
    };
    return response.arrayBuffer();

}).then(arrayBuffer => {
```

The same code is working perfectly when i use the server.

[image: run only from chrome]

[image: run with a server]

Comment: you can simply serve it in the local network from your machine. no need for an external server.

Comment: check the network tab for the error, if it's a 404 not found for example? the path is wrong or the browser can't access the location you're trying to load from

Comment: You cannot use fetch() in a file:/// environment. You need to run a local server for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a http server on the local network and serve the file there with NodeJS.

```
/* ====== create node.js server with core 'http' module ====== */
// dependencies
const http = require("http");

// PORT
const PORT = 3000;

// server create
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   if (req.url === "/") {
      res.write("This is home page.");
      res.end();
   } else if (req.url === "/about" && req.method === "GET") {
      res.write("This is about page.");
      res.end();
   } else {
      res.write("Not Found!");
      res.end();
   }
});

// server listen port
server.listen(PORT);

console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`);

// ======== Instructions ========
// save this as index.js
// you have to download and install node.js on your machine
// open terminal or command prompt
// type node index.js
// find your server at http://your.network.ip.address:port/
```

learn about it here: [How could others, on a local network, access my NodeJS app while it's running on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on)

Comment: I have no admin access to my pc or in local network. The folder is in a public storage in file server of my work.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that i know is to wrap it in electron or tauri. Electron app run without installing, tauri should be also possible to do so I guess.