# How to connect an Android Studio app to a real device? (error: "no data")

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, http, networking

I've developed an Android app that works perfectly on an emulator but displays the error message:

> we did not get any data

When I run it on a real device (Samsung S9). I suspect the problem is with how I'm connecting to my backend.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- Verified USB debugging is enabled on the device
- Connected with a reliable USB cable

**Code (Most Relevant Parts):**

**Relevant part of AndroidManifest.xml:** (especially any network-related permissions)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**app_constants.dart:** (Focus on BASE_URL)

```
class AppConstants {
  static const String BASE_URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080"; 
  // ... other constants
}
```

I'm grateful for any help you might be able to give.

Comment: Sorry, I can't*

Comment: You might want to "divide and conquer". Remove code until it works on your real device. This may help you locate the bug. However, without any code or any other description this question will likely get closed.

Comment: Hello, I added some code

Comment: Is the ip address the address of your local PC?

Comment: No, it's not my local pc IP address

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I tried it.

Comment: For me, it works when I run the app with an android emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.0.2.2 is a special alias to your host loopback interface i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine. You may be able to change your `AppConstants` to your LAN address if your device and backend are running on the same LAN. This may require additional configuration to get it to work.

```
class AppConstants{
  static const String BASE_URL="http://192.168.xx.xx:8080";
  static const String GET_TASKS="/gettasks";
  static const String POST_TASK="/create";
  static const String GET_TASK="/gettask/";
  static const String UPDATE_TASK="/update/";
  static const String DELETE_TASK="/delete/";
}
```

You may use `ifconfig -a` to get your LAN IP.

Comment: More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808560/why-do-we-use-10-0-2-2-to-connect-to-local-web-server-instead-of-using-computer

Comment: I changed the IP to IPv4 Address  and it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean with that? What did you set BASE_URL to?

Comment: Test if your webapp is accessible with that BASE_URL on your phone. Open it with a web browser on your device

Comment: How can I do it? Step by step, please.

Comment: Enter http://192.168.0.4:8080 in you phone's browser's (for example Chrome) address bar and press enter. If it's not accessible then it might be blocked by a firewall or similar, but that's another question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on for a similar issue.

Comment: it's not accessible, what I have to do in that case?

Comment: That's probably the ip address of your router, not of your machine that is running the backend. You deleted your previous comment so the conversation now is misleading. Check the similar issue i posted in the previous comment and ask a separate question if you still can't get it to work because it's a separate issue.

Comment: Even if I tried to run the app by USB connection?

Answer (score 1):

Based on `static const String BASE_URL="http://192.168.xx.xx:8080"`
requests which are outside SSL Encryption, add:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

To the `AndroidManifest.xml`