# Deploy a node js application on fedora workstation 36

Tags: node.js, server, nodejs-server

I have a nodejs application that i wanted to deploy on a local server(which is running Fedora 36). I have developed the NodeJS side on another pc,and it works fine when the node is running. But when i copy the node server directory to the fedora serve and run it,it only works on local host. I couldnot access the server even if i'm in the same network.
I'm developing the  app for a small locally connected PC and i donot want to use the hosting companies as well as Heroku. Is the it the firewall that is blocking my request to the server? What option do i have to host it locally? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your node.js server is running on a port determined at the end of the script usually. Sometimes 3000. but can be anything. The correct way for others to access is as you say...

```
http://your.network.ip.address:port/
or 
example ip 
http://192.168.0.3:3000
```

check your local ip and port where you run this server.
[How could others, on a local network, access my NodeJS app while it's running on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on)

Comment: I have done this but it is not working? I'm not able to  connect to the fedora.