# How to make my Ionic app backend work on android?

Tags: mongodb, express, ionic-framework, axios, ionic-vue

I'm creating an app that uses Ionic and VueJS for the front-end, and for the back-end, Express and Mongoose.
When I run the file containing the express app, it creates a localhost on port 3000 and can handle POST & GET requests. The front-end make a http POST call on localhost:3000, using axios, to send data to the database.

On my PC it works well but when I deploy the app on android it does nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: localhost will work on your PC normally but when you try to access it from another device it will not be read.. As a solution, you can either run node js to run externally within your network instead of locally in PC, or deploy your data on heroku to do your test and generally i preffer to run things externally... check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on